# How to force CMake's target_include_directories() to use absolute path

Tags: cmake

How do I force CMake's function `target_include_directories()` to treat the value as an absolute path?

For example, I want this line of code:

```
target_include_directories(foobar  PRIVATE   "%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%")
```

to simply add `%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%` to the list of include directories.

However, what we actually get is `c:\path\to\foobar\%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%`.

I ***know*** that I could do

```
target_include_directories(foobar  PRIVATE   "$ENV{FOOBAR_INCLUDE}")
```

but that's not what I want. That would expand the value of the environment variable and insert the current setting of the `FOOBAR_INCLUDE` value.

We need for it to simply push the environment variable, and then during development the developers will change the value of `FOOBAR_INCLUDE` manually without having to re-run CMake each time.

Comment: So just pass absolute path to it? `without having to re-run CMake` The whole point of cmake is that you want to re-run it in case you change configuration. Thus - you change FOOBAR_INCLUDE - you should rerun cmake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add something that looks like a relative directory (i.e. `"%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%"`) to the include directories this way. CMake will always try to manipulate these into *absolute* paths. This is more-or-less stated in the [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/include_directories.html) documentation:

> Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current source directory.

but applies to the `target_include_directories()` command as well.

Even if you try to circumvent this, and set the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the target manually:

```
set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%"
)
```

CMake will throw an error during the generation stage:

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "foobar":

    "%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%"
```

You *could* compromise, providing a **full** path, but allowing the `%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%` variable to stay:

```
target_include_directories(foobar PRIVATE "C:/%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%")
```

but this ties you and your fellow developers to the C: drive.

---

I would recommend following the approach you suggested, using an environment variable:

```
target_include_directories(foobar  PRIVATE   "$ENV{FOOBAR_INCLUDE}")
```

or creating a `FOOBAR_INCLUDE` CMake **cache** variable that can be populated by each developer before they re-run CMake. If each developer's environment is different, CMake *should* be re-configured to match that environment.

Comment: Thank you. It answers my question, even though I don't like the answer of "you can't."There are internal company development reasons that I cannot get into why it needs to actually be an un-expanded environment variable. I will have to let the powers that be know this limitation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can trick CMake into accepting literal values through generator expressions

```
target_include_directories(foobar PRIVATE $<1:%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%>)
```

This, however, won't work as CMake will generate an error about the path not being absolute.

Luckily its an include directory, so therefore you can try to add the include flag manually:

```
target_compile_definitions(foobar PRIVATE -I%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%)
```

Comment: Nice trick Micha. Sadly the idea of using -I isn't portable. That's only applicable to GCC compilers and those like it. It won't work for Windows based compiles. That's what makes `target_include_directories()` so powerful, and frustrating that it only accepts absolute paths.

Comment: (TL;DR `-I` does work for MSVC)
True, compiler flags are not "portable", they are not by nature. MSVC does mimic most basic flags 1:1, the only difference is they changed "-" for "/" _optionally_, b "-" and "/" are being used. Alternatively, `if (MSVC) target_compile_definitions(foobar PRIVATE /I%FOOBAR_INCLUDE%) else() .. endif()` would do it if you want to be pure. CMake gives the illusion of portability by having every major compiler/platform/IDE combination covered. It's very natural to have compiler/platform/IDE specific directives in CMakeLists, especially when doing very custom stuff.